# Find the User-Agent and Global IP address from using Python

Tags: python, json, ip, user-agent

Is there a way to find the user-agent and global ip in particular json format? Help me out on this.
Here is what I am trying have partial success in getting global IP but no information about user-agent.

```
import requests, json
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').json()
print r['origin']
```

Above code returning me the Global IP but I want some information regarding on which platform I am connected to the particular URL. E.g. `'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36'`.

Comment: Could you please provide more info (in detail)? What's the source?

Comment: What do you define as "global IP"? You want to get "platform information" *from whom*? Is your code a server or a client in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a JSON object as string (possibly read from a file?) you would first want to [convert that into a Python dictionary object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads)

```
import json
request_details = json.loads('{"user-agent": "Chrome", "remote_address": "64.10.1.1"}')
print request_details["user-agent"]
print request_details["remote_address"]
```

OR

If you are talking about a request that comes to the server, the user-agent is part of the request headers and remote_address is added later in the network layer.  Different web frameworks have different ways of letting you access these values.  For example Django lets you access from [HttpRequest.META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) dictionary.  Flask gives you request.headers.get("user-agent") and request.remote_addr .

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
import requests, json
r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/user-agent').json()
print r['user-agent']
```

but I would do that only when I want to verify the user-agent I'm setting in my request header.